# Why bootstrap dont working .. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement bootstrap but don't want to use any gems... 
why isn't this page working? I expect Test and Test1 to be in the same row... 
I only include the bootstrap.css ( no bootstrap  javascript )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ggame</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="VGd6MVDES7+g0kmsvXeJWXXv/xYfxZjWR7yFqkn7HBA=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class ="span8">
       Test
      <div class="span4"> 
        Test1 
       </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.span` class in Bootstrap 3, use the `.col` classes to get the desired output:

```
   <div class ="col-md-8">
    Test
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Test1 
   </div>
```

Also have a look at the bootstrap grid system for more examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/